# Install vue/cli and vue/cli-service-global through package.json?

Tags: vue.js

Each time I install/build my vue.js project from scratch (e.g. in a new/fresh git clone) I run:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
npm install -g @vue/cli-service-global
npm install
```

Is is possible to move:

```
@vue/cli
@vue/cli-service-global
```

into my `package.json` file so they will get installed along side my other dependencies and I can just run:

```
npm install
```

to prepare my project?

Or are both:

```
@vue/cli
@vue/cli-service-global
```

"special" in the sense that they are not project specific dependencies but more like system wide tools like `npm`, `node`, `git` etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your package.json under scripts you need to add preinstall script which will execute preinstall scripts every time you do `npm install` ,
as follow:

```
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm i -g @vue/cli @vue/cli-service-global"
  }
```